# Nested loops: Print seats in java

Tags: java, nested-loops

Given numRows and numCols, print a list of all seats in a theater. Rows are numbered, columns lettered, as in 1A or 3E. Print a space after each seat, including after the last. Use separate print statements to print the row and column. Ex: numRows = 2 and numCols = 3 prints:
1A 1B 1C 2A 2B 2C

My code's like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numRows = 2;
    int numCols = 3;
    int rows = 0;
    int cols = 1;
    char col;

    while (rows < numRows) {

        rows++;

        col='A';

        while (cols <= numCols) {
            System.out.print("" + rows + col + " ");
            col++;
            cols++;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(" ");

    return;

}

}
```

And my output's like:

```
1A 1B 1C
```

I tried to make it like:

```
1A 1B 1C 2A 2B 2C
```

Why my loop stop at 1?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Gui, this looks like a homework question. To learn programming you need to trace these errors by debugging your code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a line `cols = 1;` just after `rows++;`

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I came up with for this particular ZyBooks challenge (I used my own iterables instead of their pre-defined ones out of habit):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class NestedLoops {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int numRows;
      int numColumns;
      int currentRow;
      int currentColumn;
      char currentColumnLetter;

      numRows = scnr.nextInt();
      numColumns = scnr.nextInt();

      for (int i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {

         currentColumnLetter = 'A';

         for (int x = 1; x <= numColumns; x++) {
            System.out.print(i);
            System.out.print(currentColumnLetter + " ");
            currentColumnLetter++;
         }

      }

      System.out.println("");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't reset the value of `cols` in the outer loop. So the second time through the outer loop, the inner loop never gets run at all. Also consider using a `for` loop:

```
for (int rows = 0; rows < numRows; ++rows) {
    // ...
    for (int cols = 0; cols < numCols; ++cols) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but I am going through this same challenge in zybooks. My initial code is a little different and the answers above were a little off from what the IDE was testing for. So I decided to copy and paste my code in case anyone needs a little help with this challenge.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NestedLoops {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int numRows;
      int numColumns;
      int currentRow;
      int currentColumn;
      char currentColumnLetter;

  numRows = scnr.nextInt(); // user input for how many rows
  numColumns = scnr.nextInt(); // user input for many columns

  /* Your solution goes here  */ 
  currentRow = 0; // Must be intialized to 0 or a "2" will print before "1"
 while (currentRow < numRows) { // Intialized the loop
    currentRow++; // increments the currentRow
    currentColumnLetter = 'A'; // Sets the first column to char 'A'
    currentColumn = 1; // Define to intialize inner loop
    while (currentColumn <= numColumns) { // Will initial for any positive input 1 +
       System.out.print(currentRow); // Asked specifically for 2 printouts
       System.out.print(currentColumnLetter + " "); // 2nd printout with space at end.
       currentColumnLetter++; // increments the Letter
       currentColumn++; // increments the column
    }
 }


  System.out.println("");
   }
}
```

I hope this helps anyone needing a little help with this assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the position of `cols = 1;`

```
public static void main(final String[] args){
        int numRows = 2;
        int numCols = 3;
        int rows = 0;


        while (rows < numRows) {

            rows++;
            int cols = 1;
            char col = 'A';

            while (cols <= numCols) {
                System.out.print("" + rows + col + " ");
                col++;
                cols++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the first iteration, when it goes over the inner while, you update the value of "cols".
So when this while is done, cols = 3.

Then on the second iteration, you still have cols=3 which is > numCols so it doesn't execute the while loop.

As said Parasu just add "cols = 1;" before the inner loop and it'll works.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a for loop

```
public class NestedLoops {
public static void main (String [] args) {


    int numRows = 2;
      int numCols = 3;


      int i = 0;
      int j = 0;
      char rows;
      char columns;

      rows = '1';
      for (i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
         columns = 'A';
         for (j = 0; j < numCols; ++j) {
            System.out.print("" + rows + columns + " ");
            columns++;
         }
         rows++;
      }


      System.out.println("");

      return;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NestedLoops_2 {
       public static void main (String [] args) {
          int numRows = 2;
          int numCols = 5;

for (int i = 1; i <= numRows; i++){ 
          char abc = 'A';
          for (int j = 1; j <= numCols; ++j) {
          System.out.print("" + i + abc + " ");
          ++abc;     
          }
    }
          System.out.println("");
          return;
       }
    }
```

Comment: int i = 0;
      int j = 0;
      char rows;
      char columns;

      rows = '1';   - just don't need all of that

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just make a small change in your code. After the inner while loop but just inside the outer while loop write cols=1;... because the next time when the loop reaches the same inner while loop cols have to again start at 1 and not at some other value .

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NestedLoops {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int numRows;
      int numColumns;
      int currentRow;
      int currentColumn;
      char currentColumnLetter; //not needed

      numRows = scnr.nextInt();
      numColumns = scnr.nextInt();
      String currentColumnL;
      char[] alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
      for(currentRow = 1; currentRow <= numRows; currentRow = currentRow + 1) {
         for(currentColumn = 1; currentColumn <= numColumns; currentColumn = currentColumn + 1) {
            currentColumnL = Character.toString(alphabet[currentColumn-1]);
            System.out.print("" + currentRow + currentColumnL + " ");
   }
}

      System.out.println("");
   }
}
```

This is my solution to 4.7.2: Nested loops: Print seats, I did not use char currentColumnLetter

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution. This one was really tough!

One thing to point out, you cannot print the string and the char within the same print statement. I'm not sure why but it will not run if you do.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NestedLoops {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int numRows;
      int numColumns;
      int currentRow;
      int currentColumn;
      char currentColumnLetter;

      numRows = scnr.nextInt();
      numColumns = scnr.nextInt();
   
      
      for(currentRow = 1; currentRow <= numRows; currentRow++){
         // Set the starting column letter
         currentColumnLetter = 'A';
         
         
         for(currentColumn = 0; currentColumn < numColumns; currentColumn++){
            System.out.print(currentRow);
            System.out.print(currentColumnLetter + " ");
            
            
            currentColumnLetter++;
         }
      }

      System.out.println("");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I came up with using C++ in my class:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int numRows;
  int numColumns;
  int currentRow;
  int currentColumn;
  char currentColumnLetter;

  cin >> numRows;
  cin >> numColumns;
  for (currentRow = 1; currentRow <= numRows; currentRow++) {

     currentColumnLetter = 'A';

    for (currentColumn = 1; currentColumn <= numColumns; currentColumn++) {
        cout << currentRow;
        cout << currentColumnLetter << " ";
        currentColumnLetter++;
     }
  }

  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Passed all test in ZyBooks

```java
numRows = scnr.nextInt();
numColumns = scnr.nextInt();

for (currentRow=1; currentRow<=numRows; currentRow++) {
    currentColumnLetter='A';
    for (currentColumn=0; currentColumn<numColumns; currentColumn++) {
        System.out.print(currentRow);
        System.out.print(currentColumnLetter+(" "));
        currentColumnLetter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stakoverflow. Some explanatory words about your codes, besides that it works but also how would be helpful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).